# cURL function returning false in simple GET request

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am working on this for 2 hours and just can't figure out what's wrong. I am making a cURL get request with just the URL (with parameters) and the response is expected to be some kind of access_token in JSON format but I am continually getting an error: the `curl_exec()` function is returning `false`. The URL is alright because directly pasting the prepared URL to the browser address bar gives the appropriate access_token. You may need to know that I am making a graph API (Facebook) request. Here is some code:

```
private function getAccessToken() {
            $uri = $this->prepareTokenUri(); // getting the uri
            echo "<strong>$uri</strong><br/>"; // printing the uri for debugging purpose
            $this->setCurlToGet($uri);  // explained below
            $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
            echo "<b>Here Goes Response</b>";
            var_dump($response); // boolean false
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
            $this->token_expires = $response['expires_in'];
            $this->token_type = $response['type'];
            return $response['access_token'];
        }
```

The function `setCurlToGet()` just does the following:

```
// call this function only when making a GET request
private function setCurlToGet($url) {
            $this->unsetCurl();
            $this->curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            return $this->curl;
        }
```

and the `unsetCurl()` method is as follows:

```
private function unsetCurl() {

            if(!is_null($this->curl)) {
                curl_close($this->curl);
                $this->curl = null;
            }
        }
```

I have var_dumped() everything, the cURL resource variable (`$this->curl`) and it is actually a curl resource variable. The call to `curl_exec()` is returning false and I just can't figure out why. Again, I would like to repeat that there is nothing wrong with the URL because when the printed url (in the line `echo "<strong>$uri</strong><br/>";`) is copied and pasted in browser's address bar, result is an access_token that I need.

In case you wanted to see the pattern of URI that `prepareTokenUri()` is preparing:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?client_id={my-appid}&redirect_uri={response-handler-script-uri}&client_secret={app-secret-code}&code={a-long-code}`

Comment: Does `curl_error()` show anything?

Comment: should ideally work. do change the private to public just to check

Comment: @AbraCadaver Just checked. It says 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'. Now how to solve this thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=curl%20SSL%20certificate%20problem%3a%20unable%20to%20get%20local%20issuer%20certificate

Comment: @AbraCadaver WoW, and I was dying. Thank you for saving my night :)

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix:

Add these lines to your `setCurlToGet` function in same area as other curl_setopt methods.

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

The only issue with this is that if someone is able to make dns go to their server, instead of facebook as expected from url, that you are not verifying that it is indeed facebook.

So if you are worried about that, the proper fix:

1) Download cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

2) Add the following line to php.ini, with correct path of where you put the above file

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

3) Reload apache service